# bibliography style, Elsevier

Tags: bibliographies

I am writing a journal paper using Texstudio. I have the problem that using the following preamble the result of the bibliography style is the following in the text of my paper

[image: example of how my bibliography appear in my paper]

The preamble used in my paper is the following

```
\documentclass[preprint,12pt,authoryear]{elsarticle}
% !TeX spellcheck = en_US 
\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{detect-weight, detect-display-math}
\sisetup{detect-inline-weight=math}
\sisetup{mode=text,per-mode=symbol}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usetikzlibrary{plotmarks}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\usepgfplotslibrary{patchplots}
\newlength\fwidth
\setlength{\fwidth}{0.8\textwidth}
\pgfplotsset{plot coordinates/math parser=false}
\usepackage{overpic}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{hyperref,url}
\newcounter{bibcount}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@lbibitem}{\item[}{\item[\hfil\stepcounter{bibcount}{\thebibcount.}}{}{}
\setlength{\bibhang}{2\parindent}
\renewcommand\NAT@bibsetup%
[1]{\setlength{\leftmargin}{\bibhang}\setlength{\itemindent}{-\parindent}%
    \setlength{\itemsep}{\bibsep}\setlength{\parsep}{\z@}}
\makeatother
\bibliographystyle{agsm}
\usepackage{bicaption}
\usepackage{makecell}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\bfseries}
\renewcommand\theadgape{}
\usepackage[skip=1ex, labelfont=bf]{caption}
\usepackage[skip=0.333\baselineskip]{caption}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
\def\UrlFont{\normalfont}
\sisetup{per-mode=symbol}
\usepackage[margin=2.5cm]{geometry} 
\usepackage[skip=0.333\baselineskip]{caption}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath}

\journal{fuel}

\begin{document}


\section*{References}
\bibliography{bilbiography}

%% else use the following coding to input the bibitems directly in the
%% TeX file.

\end{document}

\endinput
```

A reviewer told me that the references should be numbered and appear in the order they appear in the text.

I don't know how fix this problem. Could anyone help me?

Comment: I forgot say that the references should appear numbered in the text of my paper.

Comment: Just drop the `authoryear` option in the `\documentclass` directive. Also, the `agsm` bibliography style can only generate authoryear-type citation call-outs. You need to switch to a bibliography style that can generate numeric-style citation call-outs. Since you're using the `elsarticle` document class, I suggest you employ the `elsarticle-num` bibliography style. After changing the argument of `\bibliographystyle`, be sure to run a full recompile cycle: LaTeX, BibTeX, and LaTeX twice more.

Comment: Incidentally, there's no need to load the `natbib` package explicitly, as this package is loaded automatically by the document class. Also, load the `url` and `hyperref` packages *last*, and be sure to load `hyperref` after, not before, `url`.

Comment: BTW, nothing good is going to come from loading the `caption` package three separate times.

Comment: Thank all for the comments! However the problem of list the bibliography according it appear on the text , did not work. 
In the bibliography section, it appear alphabetically. I would that it appear according the bibliography was cited in the paper.

Comment: Please be more specific as to what "did not work" means. Are you maybe not getting numeric-style citation call-outs? Incidentally, the requirement that the references mustn't be sorted alphabetically is rather important. To get the bibliographic entries ordered by the occurrence of their first citation in the document, I suggest you use the `unsrtnat` bibliography style.

Comment: Please, look this post where I explain my problem with the bibliography https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/431914/list-the-bibliography-according-it-appear-in-the-text