# List the bibliography according it appear in the text

Tags: bibliographies

I am writing a article for Elsevier, and I would like that the bibliography appear in the section of "references" according the citations are appearing in the text.

For example

[image: introduction of my paper]

I would like that the reference 29 appear like the reference number 1 instead of 29.

I am working with the following preamble

```
\documentclass[preprint,12pt]{elsarticle}
% !TeX spellcheck = en_US 
\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{detect-weight, detect-display-math}
\sisetup{detect-inline-weight=math}
\sisetup{mode=text,per-mode=symbol}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usetikzlibrary{plotmarks}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\usepgfplotslibrary{patchplots}
\newlength\fwidth
\setlength{\fwidth}{0.8\textwidth}
\pgfplotsset{plot coordinates/math parser=false}
\usepackage{overpic}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\bibliographystyle{abbrvnat}
\usepackage{bicaption}
\usepackage{makecell}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\bfseries}
\renewcommand\theadgape{}
\usepackage[skip=1ex, labelfont=bf]{caption}
\usepackage[skip=0.333\baselineskip]{caption}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
\def\UrlFont{\normalfont}
\sisetup{per-mode=symbol}
\usepackage[margin=2.5cm]{geometry} 
\usepackage[skip=0.333\baselineskip]{caption}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\journal{Fuel}
\begin{document}

\section{Introduction}
Oil shales (OS) are fine grain sedimentary rocks that contain organic material of high molecular weight, called kerogen, disseminated in its inorganic matrix [\cite{scouten1990fuel}, \cite{allred1982oil}].

\section*{References}
\bibliography{bilbiography}

%% else use the following coding to input the bibitems directly in the
%% TeX file.

\end{document}

\endinput
```

The bibliography has 37 references, and I would that each reference appear in the bibliography according it appear in the text.

Could anyone help me?

Comment: the problem could not be fixed using your recomendation.

Answer (score 1):

You need to

- change the argument of `\bibliographystyle` from `abbrvnat` (which performs alphabetical sorting by authors' surnames) to `unsrtnat` (which performs no sorting); then,
- perform a full recompile cycle: LaTeX, BibTeX, and LaTeX twice more.

Here's a screenshot of a simplified version of your MWE (minimum working example); observe that the Scouten entry, which is cited first, is numbered `1`, whereas the Allred entry is numbered `2`. Correspondingly, the Scouten entry is listed before the Allred bibliography in the references.

[image]

In the following, I've also tried to clean up, simplify, and organize the preamble code.

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
%% create a dummy bib file
\begin{filecontents}{bilbiography.bib} 
@misc{allred1982oil,
  author = "Allred",
  title  = "Oil",
  year   = 1982,
}
@misc{scouten1990fuel,
  author = "Scouten",
  title  = "Fuel",
  year   = 1990,
}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass[preprint,12pt]{elsarticle}
\journal{Fuel}
\bibliographystyle{unsrtnat} % not 'abbrvnat'

\usepackage[margin=2.5cm]{geometry} 
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath,booktabs,
            graphicx,pdflscape,float}
\usepackage{etoolbox} % do you need this package?
\usepackage{bicaption}% ditto

\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{detect-weight, 
         detect-display-math,
         detect-inline-weight=math,
         mode=text,
         per-mode=symbol}

\usepackage{pgfplots,overpic}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usetikzlibrary{plotmarks}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\usepgfplotslibrary{patchplots}
\newlength\fwidth
\setlength{\fwidth}{0.8\textwidth}
\pgfplotsset{plot coordinates/math parser=false}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15} % conflict with 'compat=newest' (see above)!

\usepackage{makecell}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\bfseries}
\renewcommand\theadgape{}

\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup{labelfont=bf,skip=0.333\baselineskip}

\usepackage{tabularx}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}

\usepackage[hyphens,spaces,obeyspaces]{url}
\def\UrlFont{\normalfont}
\usepackage[colorlinks,allcolors=blue]{hyperref}

\begin{document}
Oil shales (OS) are \dots\ inorganic matrix \cite{scouten1990fuel,allred1982oil}.

\section*{References}
\bibliography{bilbiography} % sic [!]
\end{document}
```